# Constexpr Sorted Unique Container Set as Array wrapper

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, set, compile-time

I want to create a constexpr container like std::array that is also sorted and all elements are unique. What I want to achieve is to check at compile time if the given data in the constructor are sorted and unique. I believe an std::set interface is more close to what I want to achieve but it is not constexpr (yet?). I plan to create a wrapper and use an std::array internally while I expose the std::set interface externally.

The current implementation looks like this

```
struct ConstexprSet
{
    constexpr ConstexprSet(const std::array<DataType, Size>& data) : mData(data)
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_sorted(std::cbegin(mData), std::cend(mData)))
            throw std::runtime_error("Data not sorted");
        if constexpr (std::adjacent_find(std::cbegin(mData), std::cend(mData)) != std::cend(mData))
            throw std::runtime_error("Data not unique");
    }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto GetData() const noexcept { return mData; }
private:
    std::array<DataType, Size> mData;
};
```

The error I get is that "this" is not a constant expression. If I change the mData with the data argument I get that data is not a constant expression. So what is a constant expression after all?
If I pass the whole array as an NTTP will this work?

The desired use case would be something like this

```
constexpr ConstexprSet features{"A"sv, "B"sv, "C"sv, "D"sv, "E"sv, "F"sv};
```

where the template arguments will be deduced from the input arguments like it is done in the std::array.

The following two examples should not compiled successfully and they should give comprehensive messages

```
constexpr ConstexprSet features{"A"sv, "D"sv, "C"sv, "B"sv, "E"sv, "F"sv}; // Data not sorted
constexpr ConstexprSet features{"A"sv, "B"sv, "B"sv, "D"sv, "E"sv, "F"sv}; // Data not unique
```

An other failed experiment was to create a constructor with an initializer list and pass it straight to the internal array but that does not work either...

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem or any other approach I can follow to achieve the desired behavior of this container would be more than welcome

The current draft I used for experimentation can be found here https://godbolt.org/z/1468cEjhW

Comment: With the precious help of @passing_through and some experimentation a full working example can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fcodoqvds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```cpp
> struct ConstexprSet {
>     std::array<DataType, Size> mData;
> ```

You can't do that - at the class level, `DataType` and `Size` aren't even declared identifiers.

Let's declare them (`T` for `DataType`, `n` for `Size`):

```cpp
template<typename T, auto n> class Set {
    std::array<T, n> mData;
// TODO
```

> What I want to achieve is to check at compile time if the given data in the constructor are sorted and unique

Then you need a constructor which is [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) (***must*** be run at compile-time), not `constexpr` (runtime/compile-time "polymorphic"):

```cpp
public:
    consteval Set(auto... ts): mData{std::move(ts)...} {
        if (n == 0) return; // can't think of a ready STL algorithm
        for (auto prev = mData.begin(), cur = prev + 1; cur != mData.end(); ++prev, ++cur)
            if (*prev >= *cur)
                throw std::logic_error{"not sorted / not unique"};
    }
};
```

A deduction guide for convenience:

```cpp
Set(auto t, auto... ts) -> Set<decltype(t), sizeof...(ts) + 1>;
```

Tests:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr Set set1{"A"sv, "B"sv, "D"sv}; // ok
    constexpr Set set2{"A"sv, "D"sv, "B"sv}; // error
    constexpr Set set3{"A"sv, "D"sv, "D"sv}; // error
}
```

> should give comprehensive messages

```
source>:24:16: error: constexpr variable 'set2' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr Set set2{"A"sv, "D"sv, "B"sv}; // error
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:17:5: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
                                throw std::logic_error{"not sorted / not unique"};
```

```
source>:25:16: error: constexpr variable 'set3' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr Set set3{"A"sv, "D"sv, "D"sv}; // error
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:17:5: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
                                throw std::logic_error{"not sorted / not unique"};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `consteval` was what I was needed. Also the deduction guide worked perfectly. I noticed that the check of the unique/sorted can be replaced by  adjacent_find like that ``if (std::adjacent_find(std::cbegin(mData), std::cend(mData), std::greater_equal<DataType>()) != std::cend(mData))
                throw std::logic_error("Data are not unique / not sorted");``

Comment: However I am not sure if I have to also check for `std::is_constant_evaluated()` in the constructor since there is no `if consteval` syntax like `if constexpr`

Comment: @Jason it gives you nothing - `consteval` functions/constructors always are_constant_evaluated :) E.g. `int main() { auto runtime = "C"sv; Set{runtime}; }` produces `<source>:27:5: error: call to consteval function 'Set<std::basic_string_view<char>, 1UL>::Set<std::basic_string_view<char>>' is not a constant expression
    Set{runtime};
<source>:27:9: note: read of non-constexpr variable 'runtime' is not allowed in a constant expression
    Set{runtime};`